# Django class based view, define method and property

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm caching a view's html output.  (I'm caching a view response (html) myself without using django's caching framework.)

I need to invalidate this cache in various places.
eg) Suppose I develop StackOverflow (woohoo), and caches its main-page.
I definately want to invalidate the cache whenever a new question is posted.
or new `featured` article needs to be shown in the main page.

Among other things, I would like to store `cache_key` for the main page, and `invalidate_page` (a function) somewhere near `main page` 's view code.

I could define them separately near `main_page` view. but just thought it would be nicer for the main_page view to have those constants, methods attached to itself.

I'd like to encapsulate stuff in `main_page view` somehow as we do with object oriented programming if it's possible.

I only use FBV and thought maybe CBV can help here, but any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I cannot understand your question, sorry. Could you add more details and maybe an example that shows the problem?

Comment: I updated the OP a bit. hope it helps to clarify my question.

Comment: You can add arbitrary attributes to functions and methods. For example, suppose you have a `main_view` function, you can write `main_view.cache_key = 'abc'` after defining it. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, what about adding functions to main_view?

Comment: You can do that too. You can add whatever attribute you want